# Anybody know of a good logic layout application?

Tags: logic

I don't know exactly what to call this kind of application, but I'm looking for a good program that'll allow me to layout and test logical circuits. Something that has ands, ors, xors, nots, transistors, and all the basic logical components. Something kind of like UML except with basic electrical components. Something that could generate something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [theseusresearch.com](http://www.theseusresearch.com/images/NCLARTFIG27.gif))</sub>

Comment: Using/looking for a program != programming.  Voting to close as not programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [TinyCAD](http://tinycad.sourceforge.net/). It does SPICE simulation as well as schematic capture.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, [SPICE](http://bwrc.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icbook/SPICE/) was an application that could do this sort of thing.

Perhaps [Open Circuit Design](http://www.opencircuitdesign.com/).

I'm not an expert - I was a mechanical engineer, not electrical.

Comment: SPICE is a net-list descriptive language rather than a GUI type tool which the OP means. You'd have to be mental to hand write some SPICE -- it's the kind of gibberish the gate-synthesisers produce.

Comment: Thanks for the correction - like I said, I was a mechanical engineer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to mention a "fun" one that I've contributed source code to: Multimedia Logic http://www.softronix.com/logic.html

It has a lot of features and is good for educational purposes. It should easily handle circuits of the kind in your example. See http://www.dst-corp.com/james/virtualdigitalprojects/Main.asp for advanced examples.

Let me say, however, for serious non-educational work, you need something more professional.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about the digital rather than the electron realm then you could go for Mentor Graphics or Cadence, but they cost £20000000000000000000000000000000000 each.

FYI: The term you're after is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematic_editor . Now you know the term, knock yourself out googling for freeware ones. I've used one or two, but they were always terribly buggy compared to Cadence/Mentor (which themselves are terribly buggy, but in really expensive ways)

Unless you're talking about a tool that makes the metal mask layout? The only one of those I've ever seen is in Cadence iteslf. I doubt there's a freeware layout tool. If you find one, let us know :)

If you don't know what you mean, here are some pictures ot help.
A metal layout tool looks like this:
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/cs168/cs168-04win/lab2/lab2_2.jpg
(That's a single invertor by the looks of it)

A schematic design tool looks like this:
http://www.ema-eda.com/images/products.orcad.tech.pcblayout.gif

EDIT: You added your own picture, which clearly shows you mean a schematic editor :)